# project euler #7 in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

Here is a question:

> By listing the first six prime
>   numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13, we
>   can see that the 6th prime is 13.
>
> What is the 10001st prime number?

Here is my solution:

```
#lang racket

(define (search-limit num)
  (+ (floor (sqrt num)) 1))

(define (search-list num)
  (stream->list (in-range 2 (search-limit num))))

(define (divided? num x)
  (= (remainder num x) 0))

(define (list-of-dividers num)
  (filter (lambda (x)
            (divided? num x))         
       (search-list num)))

(define (prime? num)
  (= (length (list-of-dividers num)) 0))

(define (problem_7 current_prime primes counter)
  (cond
    [(< primes 10001)
     (cond
       [(prime? counter) (problem_7 counter (+ primes 1) (+ counter 1))]
       [else (problem_7 current_prime primes (+ counter 1))])]
    [else current_prime]))

(problem_7 0 0 0)
```

It works but works slowly.  I am sure that there is a better solution.
Can you give me the more scheme-way solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it the following way, which takes under 1 second on my computer (your version took about 12.5 seconds):

```
#lang racket

(define (divides? n div)
  (= (remainder n div) 0))

(define (prime? n)
  (prime-helper n 2))

(define (prime-helper n start)
  (cond ((> start (sqrt n)) #t)
        ((divides? n start) #f)
        (else (prime-helper n (+ 1 start)))))

(define (prob7_helper n count)
  (cond ((= 10001 count) (- n 1))
        ((prime? n) (prob7_helper (+ 1 n) (+ 1 count)))
        (else (prob7_helper (+ 1 n) count))))

(define (prob7) (prob7_helper 2 0))

(prob7)
```

There are certainly faster implementations of `(prime? n)`, but this does the trick for me.

Comment: The if block around the (= (remainder n div) 0) in divides? is redundant. But I guess that is a bit nit-picky

Comment: Good catch -- I'll fix it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Composite numbers always have a smaller prime number as a divisor; prime numbers never have a a smaller prime as a divisor. Since you're generating primes in sequence, you can exploit this fact by making your primality test just try dividing your candidate by the list of smaller primes. (This is a variation on the Sieve of Eratosthenes method, incidentally.)

Comment: Also, you should only test numbers in the form of 6*K+1 and 6*K-1

Comment: Every prime number greater than 3 is 6k +/- 1 for some positive integer k. It's a fun, tiny little math puzzle to figure out why.